# PHP require_once giving an failed to open stream error

Tags: php

This is my folder structure

```
├── css
│   └── Style.css
├── js
│   └── Main.js
├── php
│   └── api
│       ├── abstract
│       │   └── Query.php
│       ├── config
│       │   └── Connection.php
│       └── object
│           ├── Project.php
│           └── Task.php
├── Index.php
└── Overview.php
```

From `Task.php` and `Project.php` I would like to include the `Query.php` and `Connection.php` files using this.

```
    require_once __DIR__ . "../abstract/Query.php";
    require_once __DIR__ . "../config/connection.php";
```

This is giving me two errors

```
( ! ) Warning: require_once(C:\laragon\www\WBS\php\api\object../abstract/Query.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\laragon\www\WBS\php\api\object\Project.php on line 4
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.4133  410504  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.4140  416848  require_once( 'C:\laragon\www\WBS\php\api\object\Project.php' ) ...\index.php:5

( ! ) Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\laragon\www\WBS\php\api\object../abstract/Query.php' (include_path='.;C:/laragon/etc/php/pear') in C:\laragon\www\WBS\php\api\object\Project.php on line 4
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.4133  410504  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.4140  416848  require_once( 'C:\laragon\www\WBS\php\api\object\Project.php' ) ...\index.php:5
```

VSCode does find my folders / files and gives me autocomplete recommendations, but no matter which variant I chose the errors keep showing.

I am not using any autoloader.

Comment: Always use single quotes `'hello world'` for string unless you are placing variables in your string. It improves security by preventing accidental substitutions (e.g. "I like $money$" would replace "$money" with a variable by the same name without proper sanitation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You just need a leading slash on your path. `'/../../abstract/Query.php'`**

`__DIR__` will return something like `C:/my/files`

So to extend that you want to append `/next/folder` which combines to make `C:/my/files/next/folder`.

What you have is `next/folder` which combines to `C:/my/filesnext/folder`.